# jQuery to Retrieve Data From an XML File

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, xml

i need to retrieve attribute value in the below XML :

```
<datasource id="social_messages2" serial="20140205152417255" type="feed" subtype="" mtime="2014-02-05T14:24:17.2554296Z" mtime_unix="1391610257" tz="+0100" ttl="5">
<entry id="13036083562208554600000000" ctime="2014-02-05T14:19:17.5991796Z" mtime="2014-02-05T14:19:17.5991796Z" ctime_unix="1391609958" mtime_unix="1391609958">
<field name="design">user</field>
<field name="message">RT @ThatsSarcasm: is it summer 2014 yet</field>
<field name="nickname">@devine_318</field>
<field name="mid">543606</field>
<field name="iconname"/>
<field name="timestamp">2014-01-30 15:17:46</field>
<field name="viz_image"/>
<field name="via">twitter</field>
<field name="date">2014-01-30</field>
<field name="time">15:17:46</field>
</entry>
```

for example i need to retrieve time (15:17:46) how i can write it my below code not working in this way my code work if tags like this `(<time>15:17:46</time>)` how i can retrieve the value of field see my below code :

```
function parseXml(xml) {
    $(xml).find('entry').each(function() {
        console.log(this);
        var $show = $(this);
        var via = $show.find('via').text();
        var message = $show.find('message').text();
        var time = $show.find('time').text();
        var html = '<tr><td class="bold"><img src="'+ via +'"/></td><td class="hide">' + time + '</td><td class="bold">' + message + '</td></tr>';
        $('#show_table').append($(html));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to select based on the attribute value instead of the tag name. Substitute

```
$show.find('time').text()
```

with

```
$show.find("field[name='time']").text()
```

When you supply a text with no preceeding character. Ie "text" as the selector. jQuery selects elements with that tag name. Prefixing with `.` jQuery would search for elements with a class named as the text. Eg. ".foo"  searches for elements with the foo class. However to search for an attribute value you need to tell jQuery which attributes to search and optionally. So to search any element for an attribute with the name `name` and the value `time`  you need to use the attribute selector. `[attributeName='valueToFilterOn']` which in this case would then be `[name='time']`